# How to adjust the page height to the content height?

Tags: java, height, itext, itextpdf

I'm using iTextPDF + FreeMarker for my project. Basically I load and fill an HTML template with FreeMarker and then render it to pdf with iTextPDF's `XMLWorker`.

The template is:

```
<html>
    <body style="font-family; ${fontName}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">${timestampLabel}&nbsp;</td>
                <td><b>${timestampValue}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">${errorIdLabel}&nbsp;</td>
                <td><b>${errorIdValue}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">${systemIdLabel}&nbsp;</td>
                <td><b>${systemIdValue}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">${descriptionLabel}&nbsp;</td>
                <td><b>${descriptionValue}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

String errorId = "ERROR-01";
String systemId = "SYSTEM-01";
String description = "A SHORT DESCRIPTION OF THE ISSUE";

Map<String, String> parametersMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
parametersMap.put("fontName", fontName);  //valid font name

parametersMap.put("timestampLabel",   "   TIMESTAMP:");
parametersMap.put("errorIdLabel",     "    ERROR ID:");
parametersMap.put("systemIdLabel",    "   SYSTEM ID:");
parametersMap.put("descriptionLabel", " DESCRIPTION:");

parametersMap.put("timestampValue", DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()));
parametersMap.put("errorIdValue", errorId);
parametersMap.put("systemIdValue", systemId);
parametersMap.put("descriptionValue", description);

FreeMarkerRenderer renderer = new FreeMarkerRenderer(); //A utility class
renderer.loadTemplate(errorTemplateFile);               //the file exists
String rendered = renderer.render(parametersMap);

File temp = File.createTempFile("document", ".pdf");
file = new FileOutputStream(temp);
Document document = new Document();

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(290f, 150f));
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

document.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(rendered.getBytes());


XMLWorkerFontProvider provider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
provider.register(fontFile); //the file exists
FontFactory.setFontImp(provider);
byte[] errorStyle = getErrorStyleByteArray(); //returns a byte array from a css file (works)

XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
helper.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, new ByteArrayInputStream(errorStyle), provider);

document.close();
file.close();
```

This code works fine, but With the fixed height is a problem.

I.E. Let's say that:

```
errorId = "ERROR-01"
systemId = "SYSTEM-01"
description = "A SHORT DESCRIPTION OF THE ISSUE"
```

The produced document is:

[image]

If instead I use

```
errorId = "ERROR-01"
systemId = "SYSTEM-01"
description = "A SHORT DESCRIPTION OF THE ISSUE. THIS IS MULTILINE AND IT SHOULD STAY ALL IN THE SAME PDF PAGE."
```

The produced document is:

[image]

As you can see, in the last document I have two pages. I would like to have only one page which changes its height according to the content height.

Is something like this possible with iText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the page size after you have added content to that page. One way to work around this, would be to create the document in two passes: first create a document to add the content, then manipulate the document to change the page size. That would have been my first reply if I had time to answer immediately.

Now that I've taken more time to think about it, I've found a better solution that doesn't require two passes. Take a look at [HtmlAdjustPageSize](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/HtmlAdjustPageSize)

In this example, I first parse the content to a list of `Element` objects using this method:

```
public ElementList parseHtml(String html, String css) throws IOException {
    // CSS
    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(css.getBytes()));
    cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

    // HTML
    CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(FontFactory.getFontImp());
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.autoBookmark(false);

    // Pipelines
    ElementList elements = new ElementList();
    ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
    CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()));

    return elements;
}
```

**Note:** I've been copy/pasting this method so many times that I decided to make it a static method in the `XMLWorkerHelper` class. It will be available in the next iText release.

**Important:** I have done what I promised, this method is now available in the XML Worker release.

For testing purposes, I used static `String` values for HTML and CSS:

```
public static final String HTML = "<table>" +
    "<tr><td class=\"ra\">TIMESTAMP</td><td><b>2014-11-28 11:06:09</b></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td class=\"ra\">ERROR ID</td><td><b>ERROR-01</b></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td class=\"ra\">SYSTEM ID</td><td><b>SYSTEM-01</b></td></tr>" +
    "<tr><td class=\"ra\">DESCRIPTION</td><td><b>TEST WITH A VERY, VERY LONG DESCRIPTION LINE THAT NEEDS MULTIPLE LINES</b></td></tr>" +
    "</table>";
public static final String CSS = "table {width: 200pt; } .ra { text-align: right; }";
public static final String DEST = "results/xmlworker/html_page_size.pdf";
```

You can see that I took HTML that looks more or less like the HTML you are dealing with.

I parse this HTML and CSS to an `ElementList`:

```
ElementList el = parseHtml(HTML, CSS);
```

**Or, starting with XML Worker 5.5.4:**

```
ElementList el = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HTML, CSS);
```

So far, so good. I haven't told you anything that you didn't already know, except this: I am now
 going to use this `el` twice:

1. I'll add the list to a `ColumnText` in simulation mode. This `ColumnText` isn't tied to any document or writer yet. The sole purpose to do this, is to know how much space I need vertically.
2. I'll add the list to a `ColumnText` for real. This `ColumnText` will fit exactly on a page of a size that I define using the results obtained in simulation mode.

Some code will clarify what I mean:

```
// I define a width of 200pt
float width = 200;
// I define the height as 10000pt (which is much more than I'll ever need)
float max = 10000;
// I create a column without a `writer` (strange, but it works)
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(null);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(width, max));
for (Element e : el) {
    ct.addElement(e);
}
// I add content in simulation mode
ct.go(true);
// Now I ask the column for its Y position
float y = ct.getYLine();
```

The above code is useful for only one things: getting the `y` value that will be used to define the page size of the `Document` and the column dimension of the `ColumnText` that will be added for real:

```
Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(width, max - y);
// step 1
Document document = new Document(pagesize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(pagesize);
for (Element e : el) {
    ct.addElement(e);
}
ct.go();
// step 5
document.close();
```

Please download the full [HtmlAdjustPageSize.java](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/HtmlAdjustPageSize.java) code and change the value of `HTML`. You'll see that this leads to different page sizes.

Comment: The creator of iText is answering my question on iText. That's wonderful!! Thank you very much, I'll try this as I get home

Comment: REALLY helpful example, adapted quickly for use with paragraph text, thanks. Is there an index to any examples you create Bruno?

Comment: Is there any way to implement the same but having  HTML and CSS in a single String ? As i am getting the complete HTML document from Server.

Comment: i didn't find any example. Can you please share it ? I am having one html document from server and need to convert to PDF with height according to contents with custom fonts.

Comment: @SalmanNazir Why don't you post a question showing what you have? Highjacking a question that dates from 2014 is not the way to get an answer.

Comment: posted the detail here.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506772/itextpdf-converting-large-html-to-single-page-pdf-with-custom-fonts