# itextpdf 5.5.1 Issue with PDF content resolution when converted from HTML

Tags: itext, html2pdf, xmlworker

i am working in HTML to PDF conversion using ItextPdf 5.5.1 and XMLWorker 5.5.1 in Java.
i managed to convert PDF document having height as that of HTML contents but contents in PDF looking bigger and having unwanted spaces between lines. These spaces are not there in HTML document.
[image]

```
private static void createPdf() {

    try {
        // getting HTML file from the path
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/salman.nazir/Desktop/html/tq.txt"));
        Date now = new Date();

        File file = new File(("/Users/salman.nazir/Desktop"), "my_" + now.getTime() + ".pdf");

        ElementList el = parseToElementList(is, new XMLWorkerFontProvider("resources/fonts/"));

        // width of 204pt
        float width = 204;

        // height as 10000pt (which is much more than we'll ever need)
        float max = 10000;

        //column without a `writer`
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(null);

        ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(width, max));
        for (Element e : el) {


            // Add only HTML Body Element
            // Avoiding IllegalArgumentException ("Format not found.")

            if(!e.isContent()) {
                System.out.print("META DATA");
            }
            else {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
        }
        ct.go(true);

        // Getting y posItion from simulation mode
        float y = ct.getYLine();
        Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(width, (max - y) + 25);
        // Document with predefined page size
        Document document = new Document(pagesize, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        // Getting PDF Writer
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.open();
        // Column with a writer
        ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        ct.setSimpleColumn(pagesize);
        for (Element e : el) {

            // Add only HTML Body Element
            // Avoiding IllegalArgumentException ("Format not found.")

            if(!e.isContent()) {
                System.out.print("META DATA");
            }
            else {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
        }
        ct.go();
        // closing the document
        document.close();

        showPDFPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

is there any thing to set resolution anywhere in the code ? here is HTML code that is working fine in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Lieferschein/Rechnung 27.03.17 11:18 2017/2432</title>


    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    src: url('RobotoMono-Bold.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-BoldItalic.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-Italic.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-Light.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-LightItalic.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-Medium.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-MediumItalic.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-Thin.ttf') format('ttf'), url('RobotoMono-ThinItalic.ttf') format('ttf');
}
body {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono";
    font-size: 2pt;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0pt;
}

.documentType {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

        h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0pt;
}
tr.manual_imprint td {
    border-bottom:1pt dotted black;
    height: 30pt;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h3.left {
    font-size: 13pt;
    text-align: left;
}
hr {
    height: 1pt;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    border: 0pt;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0pt;
    padding: 0pt;
    border-spacing: 0pt;
}
tr.lineitem_head td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
tr.total td {
    border-top:1pt solid black;
    border-bottom:3pt double black;
    font-size: 6pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
td {
    overflow: hidden;
}
td.left {
    max-width: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.left_indent {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 7pt;
}
td.right {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Tischlerei Helmut Meyer_676647</h1>

<h2>Winsener Landstrasse 22</h2>
<br></br>
<div class="image-container"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/gray/android-6-512.jpg"/> </div>   <h2>21423 Winsen / Luhe</h2>
<h2></h2>
<h2>Tel.: +4940441777</h2>



<h3 class="left documentType">Lieferschein/Rechnung</h3>

<table class="order">


    <tr class="lineitem_head">

        <td>Nr. 2017/2432</td>

        <td class="right">27.03.17 11:18</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="lineitems">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100%" />
        <col width="0%" />
    </colgroup>

    <tbody>

    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="3,78 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;Filter Kalita</td>
        <td class="right">4,50 €</td>

    </tr>


    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="3,03 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;Latte</td>
        <td class="right">3,60 €</td>

    </tr>


    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="7,38 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;Skywalker/250g</td>
        <td class="right">7,90 €</td>

    </tr>


    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="8,32 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;Playground Love</td>
        <td class="right">8,90 €</td>

    </tr>


    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="12,06 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;Dschaggah Khan</td>
        <td class="right">12,90 €</td>

    </tr>


    <tr class="lineitem" data-net="12,06 €">

        <td class="left">1x&nbsp;King Kongo</td>
        <td class="right">12,90 €</td>

    </tr>


    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    <tr class="total">
        <td class="left">Total</td>
        <td class="right">50,70 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="net">
        <td class="left">Netto</td>
        <td class="right">46,62 €</td>
    </tr>




    <tr class="tax">
        <td class="left">7,00 VAT</td>
        <td class="right">2,79 €</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tax">
        <td class="left">19,00 VAT</td>
        <td class="right">1,29 €</td>
    </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>


<h3>Vielen Dank für Ihren Besuch!</h3>

<h2>St-Nr.: </h2>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As your question is about html 2 pdf, you should also share an example html with resources if applicable.

Comment: html code updated

Comment: I don's see any problem with respect to the "resolution." Actually, you are creating a text-only PDF, hence resolution should never be a problem. Is it possible that you confuse the concepts of "resolution" and "leading"?

Comment: if its not about resolution then have you checked this html in browser ? on browser its working according to CSS. but in PDF the text font big, space between elements are also wider.

Comment: here what you mean by "leading"? as i double check everything on my side its creating same PDF having bigger text. can you tell me the possibilities where i am wrong ? as i posted all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to print resolution used in the parser which, by default is 72. You should design for that resolution instead of 100 or any other resolution (ie: If you'll be printing PDFs of letter size (8.5in x 11in), instead of designing for 850px by 1100px, you should do it on 612px x 792px.